# Creating a slideshow with an instagram feed

Tags: reactjs, carousel, instafeedjs, react-slick

I am trying to create a page that shows a slideshow of an instagram feed, using the libraries [instafeed.js](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js) and [react-slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick). A lot of sources writes about the ease of implementing a carousel of fotos from a feed using the [jquery slick library](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) together with instafeed.js likes this:

```
let imgFeed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'user',
  userId: '',
  clientId: '',
  accessToken: '',
  resolution: 'standard_resolution',
  template: '<img src="{{image}}" />',
  sortBy: 'most-recent',
  limit: 8,
  links: false,
  after: function () {
    $('#instafeed').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4
    });
  }
})
```

Where you simply add the slick-functionality in the after() function.

When looking through the documentation for the react-version of the slick library, dynamic content should be done like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-slick'

export default class DynamicSlides extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      slides: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }
    this.click = this.click.bind(this)
  }
  click() {
    const {slides}  = this.state
    this.setState({
      slides: slides.length === 6 ? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    })
  }
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Dynamic slides</h2>
        <button className='button' onClick={this.click}>Click to change slide count</button>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          {this.state.slides.map(function (slide) {
            return <div key={slide}><h3>{slide}</h3></div>
          })}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A lot of sources talks about how easy it is to work with the 2 libraries in making an instagram-feed-carousel without showing any solutions, so I'm kinda lost as to how to make this work, as I don't know how to get my instagram-feed dynamically added to the slider component from react-slick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with instafeed.js, but if you can get the raw data from Instagram's API, this should work for you:

```
import React from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-slick'

export default class InstagramCarousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      instagramData: this.props.instagramData
    }
  }
  render() {
    const settings = {

    }

    return (
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {this.state.instagramData.map((slide, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <a href={slide.link} target="_blank">
                <img src={slide.images.thumbnail.url} />
              </a>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </Slider>
    )
  }
}
```

If you have an access token, you can get the 20 most recent photos like so:

```
import request from 'request'

let url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='
request.get(url + accessToken, function (err, res, body) {
            this.setState({ ...this.state, instagramData: JSON.parse(body).data })
        })
```

and call the component like so:

```
<InstagramCarousel instagramData={this.state.instagramData} />
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it tomorrow and see if I can get it to work. Much appreciated!